# Maintenance Page Control

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, functional-programming, user-defined-functions

I have hmvc-codeigniter I would like to know what the best way is to show one of my views/controller pages for maintenance mode. Where I can view website but any one else that is not on my ip bets directed to this certain view/controller.

I have tried many htaccess codes but non seem to work the way I am after. They still block me from viewing my own website when working on in maintenance mode.

is there a proper function that can add in to index.php in codeingiter that can do what I am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter features the Front Controller paradigm, so everything passes through index.php. I don't know how you set your website in "maintenance mode", whether it's through a relational database or if it's just through code.

The idea above ensures that if we add code to index.php, then we know for sure that it's the entry point to our application. A quick fix would be to add the following to index.php:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx') {
    die('Application is currently in maintenance mode. Please return shortly.');
}
```

While the fix above does resolve the issue, it's never a good idea to remove content unless you have an emergency situation (hacks, DB failure, etc.). You may want to setup a different staging server, work any updates on that server, and the apply them to production.

Comment: I am going to be setting up different server think that is wise